# How to apply row limit in talend

Tags: talend

Using tdbInput I'm able to read data from Talend and after that, I'm using tmap to filter the rows. After filtration, the filtered number of rows will vary from time to time as I keep changing data in the SQL table.

Now the scenario is that when rows get filtered after using tmap if the percentage of rows pass the filtration is more than 80% then it will go to component tdboutput or else the process should not move further.

Eg: Suppose in my table no. of rows is 1000 which when filtered through tmap turns to only 600 rows then my process should stop or the flow should be redirected to tlogrow component. On the other hand, if the no. of rows is 100 and after filtration through tmap only 95 rows remain which is more than 85% then it should go to tdboutput.

Through my research I learned that in Talend I have a "global variable called NB_LINE which you can use to get the number of rows written to the component's file or table" but I'm not able to figure out how to use this information of achieve the above use case.

Please let me know how to make flow for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

global variable is the way to go I think, but this variable is only accessible on "AFTER" mode, meaning that you have to exit subjob to get the number of line processed.

useful components in this case are the pair tHashInput/tHashOutput (hidden by default but you can activate them through the "palette" menu in project settings).
With them you are able to use a cache for your data, and separate in multiple subjobs.

- one subjob to filter data
- then with IF links supporting your threshold condition, you can route to desired output.

[image]

Comment: if you don't mind can you also put screenshot of tjava and tfilterrow with explanation that how is it working? @Corentin

Comment: tFilterRow is the component where you filter your data, in your OP you had a tMap, you can keep it. 
tJava does nothing, but IF links are where the conditions are set up. (your conditions being to have more than 85% of filtered data). tJava is just here to support the IF links.

Comment: OK I got your point @Corentin, your approach is clear to me. Can you just give me the statement of the queries you have written under both if link?

Comment: i haven't been this far, but I guess if you want to have conditions on thresholds, you should use NB_LINE global variables from your tDBInput (total nb of lines) and NB_LINES in your tHashOutput (filtered lines). Check the "outline" view to get access to NB_LINE variables.

Comment: Thank you @Corentin I got your point. I simply put one formula of number of lines after tmap divided by number of lines after extraction from source *100 and found the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works.

First, find the source which can give you the exact initial number of lines.
Then after doing filtration use any component that can give you the number of lines after filtration. You can simply pass data through tjava to get the number of lines after the filtration process.

After that apply the formula mentioned below for the **run if** trigger.

[image: Picture of formula]

It should work.